# define and filling a sparse matrix using Eigen Library in C++

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to build a spars Matrix using a Eigen or Armadillo library in C++ to solve a system of linear equations Ax=b. A is the coefficient matrix with a dimension of n*n, and B is a vector of right hand side  with a dimension of n
[the Spars Matrix A is like this, see the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebptH.png)

I had a look though the Eigen document but I have a problem with defining and filling the Spars Matrix in C++.

could you please give me an example code to define the spars matrix and how to fill the values into the matrix using Eigen library in c++?

consider for example a simple spars matrix A:

1 2 0 0

0 3 0 0

0 0 4 5

0 0 6 7

```
int main()
{
     SparseMatrix<double> A;

     // fill the A matrix ????

     VectorXd b, x;
     SparseCholesky<SparseMatrix<double> > solver;
     solver.compute(A);

     x = solver.solve(b);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you read the "filling a sparse matrix" section of the doc? Simply follow the first example based on triplets: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html#title3 . This page even contains a complete example assembling and solving a Laplacian equation: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html#title1.

Answer (score 2):

The sparse matrix could be filled with the values mentioned in the post by using the `.coeffRef()` member function, as shown in this routine:

```
SparseMatrix<double> fillMatrix() {
  int N = 4;
  int M = 4;
  SparseMatrix<double> m1(N,M);
  m1.reserve(VectorXi::Constant(M, 4)); // 4: estimated number of non-zero enties per column
  m1.coeffRef(0,0) = 1;
  m1.coeffRef(0,1) = 2.;
  m1.coeffRef(1,1) = 3.;
  m1.coeffRef(2,2) = 4.;
  m1.coeffRef(2,3) = 5.;
  m1.coeffRef(3,2) = 6.;
  m1.coeffRef(3,3) = 7.;
  m1.makeCompressed();
  return m1;
}
```

However, the `SparseCholesky` module (`SimplicialCholesky<SparseMatrix<double> >`) won't work in this case because the matrix is not Hermitian. The system could be solved with a LU or BiCGStab solver. Also note that sizes of`x` and `b` need to be defined: 
`VectorXd b(A.rows()), x(A.cols());`

In case of larger sparse matrices you may also want to look at the `.reserve()`  function in order to allocate memory before filling the elements. The `.reserve()` function can be used to provide an estimate of the number of non-zero entries per column (or row, depending on the storage order. The default is comumn-major). In the example above that estimate is 4, but it does not make sense in such a small matrix. The documentation states that it is preferable to [overestimate the number of non-zeros per column](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html).

Comment: thanks very much and it is useful. yes it is very very large spars matrices. could you please explain a lit bit about the .reserve() ?

Comment: @Mortezaaminnaji I have added a an explanation and an example of  `.reserve()` as well as a link with a detailed description. I am glad to hear that you find my answer useful, but the established way to express gratitude for a useful answer on this site is to upvote it, and to accept it if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question also asks about [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net), here is the corresponding Armadillo-based code.  Best to use Armadillo version 9.100+ or later, and link with SuperLU.

```
#include <armadillo>

using namespace arma; 

int main()
{
  sp_mat A(4,4);   // don't need to explicitly reserve the number of non-zeros

  // fill with direct element access
  A(0,0) = 1.0;
  A(0,1) = 2.0;
  A(1,1) = 3.0;
  A(2,2) = 4.0;
  A(2,3) = 5.0;
  A(3,2) = 6.0;
  A(3,3) = 7.0;  // etc

  // or load the sparse matrix from a text file with the data stored in coord format
  sp_mat AA;
  AA.load("my_sparse_matrix.txt", coord_ascii)

  vec b; // ... fill b here ...

  vec x = spsolve(A,b);  // solve sparse system

  return 0;
}
```

See also the documentation for [SpMat](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat), [element access](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_access), [.load()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#save_load_mat), [spsolve()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#spsolve).

The coord file format is simple. It stores non-zeros values.
Each line contains:

```
row col value
```

The row and column counts start at zero.  Example:

```
  0 0 1.0
  0 1 2.0
  1 1 3.0
  2 2 4.0
  2 3 5.0
  3 2 6.0
  3 3 7.0
  1000 2000 9.0
```

Values not explicitly listed are assumed to be zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>                                  
#include <Eigen/Dense>                               
#include <Eigen/Sparse>                              
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double L = 5; // Length
    const int N = 120; // No of cells
    double L_cell = L / N;
    double k = 100; // Thermal Conductivity
    double T_A = 100.;
    double T_B = 200.;
    double S = 1000.;

    Vector<double, N> d, D, A, aL, aR, aP, S_u, S_p;
    vector<double> xp;


    xp.push_back((0 + L_cell) / 2.0);
    double xm = xp[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        xm = xm + L_cell;
        xp.push_back(xm);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {

        A(i) = .1;
        d(i) = L_cell;
        D(i) = k / d(i);
    }

    aL(0) = 0;
    aR(0) = D(0) * A(0);
    S_p(0) = -2 * D(0) * A(0);
    aP(0) = aL(0) + aR(0) - S_p(0);
    S_u(0) = 2 * D(0) * A(0) * T_A + S * L_cell * A(0);

    for (int i = 1; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        aL(i) = D(i) * A(i);
        aR(i) = D(i) * A(i);
        S_p(i) = 0;
        aP(i) = aL(i) + aR(i) - S_p(i);
        S_u(i) = S * A(i) * L_cell;
    }

    aL(N - 1) = D(N - 1) * A(N - 1);
    aR(N - 1) = 0;
    S_p(N - 1) = -2 * D(N - 1) * A(N - 1);
    aP(N - 1) = aL(N - 1) + aR(N - 1) - S_p(N - 1);
    S_u(N - 1) = 2 * D(N - 1) * A(N - 1) * T_B + S * L_cell * A(N - 1);

    typedef Eigen::Triplet<double> T;
    std::vector<T> tripletList;
    tripletList.reserve(N * 3);

    Matrix<double, N, 3> v; // v is declared here

    v << (-1) * aL, aP, (-1) * aR;

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < N && j < N; i++, j++)
    {
        tripletList.push_back(T(i, j, v(i, 1)));

        if (i + 1 < N && j + 1 < N)
        {
            tripletList.push_back(T(i + 1, j, v(i + 1, 0)));
            tripletList.push_back(T(i, j + 1, v(i, 2)));
        }
    }
    SparseMatrix<double> coeff(N, N);
 
    coeff.setFromTriplets(tripletList.begin(), tripletList.end());

    
    SimplicialLDLT<SparseMatrix<double> > solver;
    solver.compute(coeff);

    if (solver.info() != Success) {
        cout << "decomposition failed" << endl;
        return;
    }

    Vector<double, N> temparature;

    temparature = solver.solve(S_u);

    if (solver.info() != Success)
    {
        cout << "Solving failed" << endl;
        return;
    }

    vector<double> Te = {}, x = {};

    Te.push_back(T_A);
    x.push_back(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        Te.push_back(temparature(i));
        x.push_back(xp[i]);
    }

    Te.push_back(T_B);
    x.push_back(L);
    for (int i = 0; i < N + 2; i++)
    {
        cout << x[i] << " " << Te[i] << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a full code of a solution to numerical problem which uses `SparseMatrix`. Look at the matrix `v`. It has the values of all the nonzero elements of `coeff` matrix yet to be defined. In the next loop I made a series of `tripletList.push_back(...)` adding a *triplet* consisting of row and column index and corresponding value taken from `v` for each non-zero element of `coeff`. Now declare a Sparse Matrix `coeff` with appropriate size and use the method `setFromTriplets` ([documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html#title35)) to set its non-zero elements from `tripletList` triplets.